# save multiple record from ms access FORM to another table in one row

Tags: ms-access

I have created MS Access FORM using wizard from `tblQuestionDatabase` having field( `Questionno`, `question`, `Ans1`, `Ans2`, `Ans3`, `Ans4`), now when I open the form all records (10) coming one by one.

I have add blank textbox name `txtTypeAns` to type correct answer, now the problem is this `txtTypeAns` is not moving along with the record.

Second I want to save all 10 record in one row of another table fields ( `Name`, `Date`, `Ans1`, `Ans2`....)

Please suggest with possible code to complete this project, thanks in advance

Comment: Your question is VERY unclear. What is your current code? Use examples (code? screenshots?)

Comment: Dim SQLTxt As String

    SQLTxt = "Insert into tblTestAns (EmpName,TestDate,Ans1) Values ('" & txtName & " ','" & txtDate & " ',' " & txtAns & " ');"

     DoCmd.SetWarnings False
     DoCmd.RunSQL SQLTxt
     DoCmd.SetWarnings True
Set rst = Nothing
    Set conn = Nothing
    
End Sub

Comment: Is there is any way so I can attached access file

Comment: right-click on the table in Access, select Export, and export to comma-separated values (csv) text file, then edit your question and paste the contents of the text file if it's not too large (after pasting select what you just pasted and use the `{}` button to format it nicely). Also add your `Dim SQLTxt...` code to the original post as well, it's hard to read in the comments section.

Comment: Common question. Options: 1. Allen Browne ConcatRelated function; 2. calculate a sequence ID for each question/answers group and build CROSSTAB query with the sequence field as column heading; 3. VBA writes records to table.